# how to read structure which has array in c++

Tags: c#, interop

```
public struct Data
{
    public long id,
    public datetime time;
    public string[] atts;
    public string[] names;
};

Guid("3102C9D3-822E-4359-9383-9B3AF7D39F2C")]
public interface IData  
{
    void GetEvents([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]out DataResp[] resp);
}
```

i want to pass and receive complex structs from C# to c++ Component and populate it into c++.
the client code is like this

```
Lib::Data* data;
long size = svc->GetEvents(&data); 
for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
{  
Lib::Data& current = data[i];   
long val = current.Value;  
bstr_t unit = current.Unit;
```

can any one help me how to read string arrays from c++ and also marshal datetime.

Comment: What is the exact unmanaged (C/C++) structure type? Depending on how the arrays are set up, marshaling is done in different ways.

Comment: the structure type is the same in C++ . it will like lib::data

Comment: It cannot be the same, because `string` is a managed type. What is it, `LPWSTR`? `BSTR`? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will face several issues while doing so. Most of the time, you will have to decorate the structs with several attributes.

For passing strings, I wold recommend that you build a string of size expected by C++ using Stringbuilder which will be sufficient for it.

One more issue which I have faced several time is of packing. It changes the alignment of structure. To resolve, you should make sure that structs are sequentially aligned by providing proper attributes.

Further, if it requires you to pass any pointers, make sure you pin the objects before passing it otherwise the runtime will change it.